# How to pass focus from one element to another in Reagent(Clojurescript)?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to write reusable tag control with **reagent**. What I need to do is to focus input field after user clicks ancestor div element. To be more clear, I would like to set focus on input with class *tag-input* after user clicks div with class *form-element* How can I implement this?

```
[:div.form-element
  [:div.some-other-class
    [:ul
      [:li "entered-tag"]
    ]
  ]
  [:input.tag-input {:type "text"}]
]
```

Comment: It might actually be a better idea to make the clickable things labels with for attributes and avoid handling this in clojurescript at all.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement some oldschool click handling i guess:

```
[:div.form-element
  {:on-click #(do (println :click-click)
                  (.focus (.getElementById js/document "my-input")))}
  [:div.some-other-class
    [:ul [:li "entered-tag"]]]
    [:input.tag-input {:type "text" :id "my-input"}]]
```

so you probably should create some factory function for this form-element stuff:

```
(defn form-element [id]
  [:div.form-element
    {:on-click #(.focus (.getElementById js/document id))}
    [:div.some-other-class
      [:ul [:li "entered-tag"]]]
      [:input.tag-input {:type "text" :id id}]])
```

and use it like this:

```
[:div
  (form-element "form-element-1")
  (form-element "form-element-2")]
```

works fine for me